# How to Bypass Unwanted Spaces from Keyboard Suggestions?

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a challenge with handling keyboard suggestions in a contentEditable element. My goal is to bypass unnecessary spacing that occurs when selecting suggested text from a virtual keyboard, while still maintaining the keyboard's suggestion feature.

Using the `input` event, I can avoid unwanted spaces, but based on my implementation, this approach would cause the loss of keyboard suggestions because my implementation erases the `textContent` before replacing it with each input. This erasure seems to prevent the keyboard from tracking the `textContent` value to build suggested texts.

To circumvent this, I switched to the `keyup` event, which fires after the input and maintains the suggestion feature. However, this leads to another issue where I receive duplicated strings each time I select a key or a keyboard-suggested value. For instance, selecting the suggested text 'data' results in 'datadata ' with an additional space at the end. Likewise, inputs from keys results to dublicated strings.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm working with:

```js
const outspanin = document.getElementById('sp');

let handleglobaldblC = function (e) {
  
  // Get the content of the span 
  var content = outspanin.textContent;
  let caretPos = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
  const sub = content.slice(caretPos);
  const val2 = content.slice(0, caretPos);
     
    outspanin.textContent="";
    outspanin.textContent= val2 + sub

    setCaretPosition(val2.length);
 
}
function setCaretPosition(pos) {
  let range = document.createRange();
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(outspanin.childNodes[0], pos);
  range.collapse(false);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}

outspanin.addEventListener('keyup', handleglobaldblC);
```

```html
<html>
<style>
#sp {
    outline: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    position: relative;
    font-family: monospace; /* Ensures consistent spacing */
    background: #f3f3f3;
}

</style>
<span contentEditable=true id="sp" >continue...</span>

</html>
```

I’m looking for a workaround that avoids the unwanted spaces from suggested keyboard texts on input or keyup events while preserving the keyboard suggestions feature. Any suggestions or alternative methods to handle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a challenge with handling keyboard suggestions in a `contentEditable` element, specifically the unwanted spacing that occurs when selecting suggested text from a virtual keyboard. Here's an approach I've developed that seems to mitigate this issue:

**Approach:**

The strategy involves storing the `textContent` immediately, clearing the `textContent`, and then replacing it after a slight delay. This delay helps avoid unwanted spaces from keyboard suggestions while maintaining the suggestion feature.

**Code Solution:**

```js
const outspanin = document.getElementById('sp');

let handleglobaldblC = function (e) {
    // Get the content of the span 
    var content = outspanin.textContent;
    let caretPos = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
    const sub = content.slice(caretPos);
    const val2 = content.slice(0, caretPos);
    
    outspanin.textContent = "";
    
    // Delay before replacing back
    setTimeout(() => {
        outspanin.textContent = val2 + sub;
        setCaretPosition(val2.length);
    }, 50);
}

function setCaretPosition(pos) {
    let range = document.createRange();
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(outspanin.childNodes[0], pos);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

outspanin.addEventListener('input', handleglobaldblC);
```

```html
<html>
<style>
#sp {
    outline: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    position: relative;
    font-family: monospace; /* Ensures consistent spacing */
    background: #f3f3f3;
}

</style>
<span autocapitalize="none" contentEditable=true id="sp" >continue...</span>

</html>
```

**Limitations:**

The delay time is critical. If too short, unexpected behaviors such as loss of textContent or character repetition may occur. If too long, it can make editing feel unresponsive.
The current delay is set to 50ms, which seems to be a good balance, but further experimentation may be necessary to optimize for different devices and browsers.

**Conclusion:**

This method is not without its challenges, and there may be edge cases that require additional handling. However, it opens up a path for further research and potential improvements. If you have insights or improvements on this approach, your contributions would be greatly appreciated!